# How to use a helper method to populate a collection of radio buttons in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, radio-button

I am trying to populate a form with a collection (?) of radio buttons:

```
# _fields.html.erb

<%= f.label :invoice_type %><br/>   
<%= radio_tags_for_select(f.object.invoice_types) %>

# application_helper.rb

def radio_tags_for_select(types)   
  types_html = types.map do |type|
    content_tag :span, :class => "radio_option" do
      radio_button(:invoice_types, type, type) + type
    end
  end
  safe_join(types_html)
end
```

It seems I can't get the syntax right in this line: `radio_button(:invoice_types, type, type) + type` because the form gets displayed but no save gets persisted to the database.

Can anybody help?

Thanks...

Comment: Please check your params to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
def radio_tags_for_select(types, f)   
  types_html = types.map do |type|
    content_tag :span, :class => "radio_option" do
      f.radio_button(:invoice_type, type) + localize_address_type(type)
    end
  end
  safe_join(types_html)
end
```

Seems that I forgot to pass the object `f` before.

Please let me know if this code can be simplified. I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think U must escape raw string to html:

```
content_tag :span, :class => "radio_option" do
 raw( radio_button(:invoice_types, type, type) + type )
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but actually `safe_join(types_html)` does that pretty well.